# Как создать всплывающую кнопку в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку выводиться окно с содержанием текста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В winforms нет такого встроенного контрола. Вам придется написать либо свое решение, либо найти готовое, например [это](https://jfblier.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/window-form-expander/).

Comment: Это называется Аккордеон - Accordion. Поиск выдаст множество реализаций.